# Installing PIL in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have installed Python 3.6(on Windows 10) and I want to install also PIL to it, but I have a problem. I have read a many manuals but it is still not going. Apparently, I can not even run shell, because when I wrote to CMD python --version (I have read that it should appear something) it goes only with 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Can you help me please? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to change your %PATH% environment variable to include the Python path

Comment: @user2314737 Maybe it is stupid question, but how can I do it?

Comment: One way to do it: from a file explorer, select "This pc", with the right mouse select "Properties", --> "Advanced System Settings" --> Environment Variables, you should find the user variable Path and you can edit it there.

Comment: You also probably want Pillow (maintained fork of PIL) rather than PIL proper. To your life easier on Windows, using the [Anaconda Python distro](https://www.anaconda.com/download) is handy.